# Order of calling methods

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I'm trying to implment a file upload feature for users where they can upload multiple files at once. I'm using **[dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)** on the client side and C# in the back end. I'm using MVC razor views and I have view where the user inputs their details and upload files within the same page. So I've gone ahead and created the following methods

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadedFile(int? id)
    {
        foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //upload file here
                //file gets uploaded successfully 
            }
        }
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

I also need to store model details into the DB which are done in another method as follows

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveToDb(MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Store to db here

            int? id = viewModel.User.UserId;

            //redirect to home page if everything is ok
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Now my question is I need to run the `SaveToDb` before `UploadedFile` method because I want to pass the `int? id` as a param because I use it at the end of the file name. I really can't seem to figure out how to go about this. My client `jQuery` looks like this:

```
<script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropZone = new Dropzone("#dZUpload",{
        url: "/Home/UploadedFile",
        autoProcessQueue: false
    });
    $("#submit-all").on('click', function () {
        myDropZone.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
        myDropZone.processQueue();
    });
    myDropZone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button class='btn btn-danger'>Remove File</button>");
        var dLink = myDropZone;
        // Listen to the click event
        removeButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            // Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            // Remove the file preview.
            dLink.removeFile(file);
        });
        // Add the button to the file preview element.
        file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** `#submit-all` button also submits the entire form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to define a different method for uploading, it can e done in same post action like this :

```
<form action="~/Home/SaveDropzoneJsUploadedFiles" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneJsForm"></form>

<button id="submit-all">Submit All Files</button>

</div>

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

    Dropzone.options.dropzoneJsForm = {

        //prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
        autoProcessQueue: false,

        init: function () {
            var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
            var myDropzone = this; //closure

            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

                //tell Dropzone to process all queued files
                myDropzone.processQueue(); 
            });

        }
    };

</script>
```

}

Now on "SaveDropzoneJsUploadedFiles" action method first handle your db saving code then upload files.. this action method can also take Model parameter

Comment: I've tried this before and if I upload more than one file I get internal server error :/

Comment: Please give me stacktrace of tat error so maybe I can help you

Comment: I've gone with your approach but I'm running into some problems.. And I've posted another question explaining this which can be viewed **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745296/onclick-storing-same-value-multiple-times)**

Comment: You are still defining url in dropzone js code, why can't you define it like I explained.. and maybe when you process the queue it get hits the create action 3 times when there are 3 files so you have to change your js and just use my version of js and it will be good.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and it's exactly the same issue